# Looking for Location History Datasets of users or an efficient method to create an unbiased one

Tags: geolocation, dataset, location, privacy, scenarios

I've been trying to find a dataset of realistic location scenarios for people in New York City throughout the day for my thesis in differential privacy.

For example,I want to have a scenario for each user for 3 consecutive locations throughout the day(eg. House, Work , Night out)

I already found neighborhood tabulation areas in NYC and can recreate the home of each user, but I find it hard to create realistic scenarios for each user of Location Based Apps.

My end goal is to recreate realistic scenarios for users in NYC in order to apply differential privacy algorithms for each user and try to evaluate the efficiency of each algorithm or break it.